# Как вывести видео поток с камеры телефона на свой сайт?

Tags: html, трансляция, broadcasting, локальная-сеть, онлайн-трансляция

Как это можно сделать с помощью тега `<video>` в html5? То есть я использую какое-нибудь приложение (Например: IP Webcam) для передачи видео потока с камеры телефона через браузер. Открываю, по предложенному IP в приложении, в браузере. Хочу просто скопировать код с этого сайта html код и вставить в свой html, но на предложенном сайте видео-трансляция находиться в теге `<img>`. Мне нужно именно тег `<video>`.
Вот так выглядит тег на предложенном сайте:

```
<img src="http://192.168.1.18:8080/video ">
```

Просто переписать ссылку в тег video не выходит:

```
<video src="http://192.168.1.18:8080/video "></video>
```

Буду рад, если подскажите: как или от предложенного видеопотока перейти от `<img>` к `<video>`; или же как просто вывести видео поток в теге `<video>` видеопоток на ЛОКАЛЬНЫЙ сайт.

Comment: Думаю тут обычным HTML не обойтись, так как это стрим и постоянно нужно обновлять вью.

Comment: Захватить rtsp-поток из IP Webcam и перепаковать в HLS например через ffmpeg, расшарить HLS-файлы каким-нибудь веб-сервером например nginx, подключить какой-нибудь HLS-плеер к веб-страничке и запихнуть в него ссылку на HLS-плейлист

Comment: https://webrtc.github.io/samples/src/content/getusermedia/canvas/